# SDN5 OGM Neo4j and composite entity

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my Spring Boot, Neo4j, SDN 5 OGM project I have the following composite entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String REFERRED_BY = "REFERRED_BY";

    @Relationship(type = REFERRED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private User referrerUser;

}
```

As you may see, one user may be referred by another.

Now, I'd like to receive a paginated result:

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (u:User) " +
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[ruru:REFERRED_BY]->(ru:User) " +
        "RETURN u, ruru, ru",
        countQuery = "MATCH (u:User) " +
                "OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[ruru:REFERRED_BY]->(ru:User) " +
                "RETURN count(u)")
Page<User> findUsers(Pageable pageable);
```

I request 0-50 users. But in the real data - one of them are referred by another:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 50, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "u.createdAt"));
Page<User> userPage = userRepository.findUsers(pageable);
```

I expect not more than 50 items but as the result I receive `51` users in the `Page.getContent()`...

Is this possible to hint somehow to no include `User.referrerUser` into the `Page.content` collection and just leave it as another user entity property (reference)?

What am I doing wrong and hot to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue via @QueryResult